# Lfs 8.4 ch8. 3 : kernel config fail

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-from-scratch

I am currently following the book Linux From Scratch v8.4, i am at the kernel configuration part, part 8.3, and when i run make defconfig or make menuconfig, i have this error:

```
... YACC scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.c
bison: m4 subprocess failed: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.lib:196: scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.c] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:544: defconfig] Error 2 ...
```

Can anyone could help me how i could resolve this please ? i really really really don't want to start all over again... i followed the book and so far i didn't have any issues. I tryed to rebuild the m4 package and reinstall it but still doesn't work. How do i do to generate this zconf.tab.c ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: How come my "hello" is not printed in my message? 

Comment: Your 'goddam' made it though.

Comment: What does `ls -la /usr/bin/m4` say?

Comment: Hi, sorry took it of. Ls - la says   `- rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 827144 Aug 3 19:57 /usr/bin/m4`

Comment: Is it maybe looking for m4 in `/tools` or `/tools/bin/`?  Try to make symlinks there to /usr/local/bin/m4 and see if that works.

Comment: Mmmmm nop, actually I deleted the /tools folder as they said in the book. But I just tried to make symlinks in /tools and /tools/bin as you said and still the same error. I think it finds the m4 binary but it fail to create the zconf.tab.c or it is just missing from the package I don't know 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved in case someone else run into this issue, my m4 package was being installed only in /usr/bin, creating a symlink to /bin solved the issue.
`ln -s /usr/bin/m4 /bin/m4`